# Can I get a Scala case class definition from an Avro schema definition?

Tags: scala, schema, case-class, avro

To facilitate working with Avro in Scala, I'd like to define a case class based on the schema stored with a .avro file. I could try:

1. Writing a .scala case class definition by hand.
2. Programmatically writing strings to a .scala file
3. Spoof the case class definition with a bytecode library like
   ObjectWeb's ASM
4. SpecificCompiler tricks?
5. Modifying an existing case classed definition at runtime?

Thanks, any advice is appreciated. 
-Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you got your hands dirty with type providers at https://github.com/julianpeeters/avro-scala-macro-annotations

Comment: note: I'm not sure scala macro will be able to generate a type in the future

Answer (score 14):

I've been hacking on a little project called [Scalavro](http://genslerappspod.github.io/scalavro/) to go the other way (Scala types to Avro schemas).  It also gives you direct binary I/O.

**Simple Example:**

```
package com.gensler.scalavro.tests
import com.gensler.scalavro.types.AvroType

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val personAvroType = AvroType[Person]
personAvroType.schema
```

which yields:

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "age", "type": "int"}
  ],
  "namespace": "com.gensler.scalavro.tests"
}
```

There are many more examples on the project site (linked above) and in the scalatest specs.

I have plans to host the binaries on Sonatype OSS in the near future, but for now you can pull the source from github and `sbt publish-local` if you want to try it out.

**Update:**
*Scalavro* is now available on Maven Central.

Comment: Very nice.  Keep up the good work.  You consider making it to where there's compile-time reflection version?

Comment: Not yet, but that would be a realy fun project.  Want to help out?